# Etherpad Lite, run on Linux

Tags: jquery, linux, etherpad

I installed Xubuntu few days ago. Now I tried to run etherpad-lite on a local server (127.0.0.1:9001). After following the steps described in [github]: (https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite).

I got the following message after running it in a shell:

```
    xyz@local: ~etherpad-lite$ bin/run.sh:
Ensure that all dependencies are up to date...  If this is the first time you have run Etherpad please be patient.
npm WARN package.json async-stacktrace@0.0.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json channels@0.0.4 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ejs@0.6.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json formidable@1.0.9 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json jsdom-nocontextifiy@0.2.10 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field
npm WARN package.json tinycon@0.0.1 No repository field.
Ensure jQuery is downloaded and up to date...
Clear minfified cache...
ensure custom css/js files are created...
start...
xyz@local: ~etherpad-lite$ ....
```

The browser said: `Unable to connect Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:9001.`
After going through google, I found different approaches to that problem. 
I am not sure if my jQuery is working? The download of it failed, the shell told me that a lib is already installed.
Well, I didn't  manage to remove etherpad, (new to Linux), instead I tried the following:

```
Copy the file: /src/static/css/pad.css to /node_modules/ep_oae/static/css/pad.css
configure the file settings.json.template:
Change: "socketTransportProtocols" : …  to "socketTransportProtocols" : ["websocket", "xhr-polling", "jsonp-polling", "htmlfile"], 
and "defaultPadText": …. to "defaultPadText": " "

Finally delete the following part of code in the bin/run.sh file: 
#Stop the script if its started as root
if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 0 ] && [ $ignoreRoot -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "You shouldn't start Etherpad-Lite as root!"
   echo "Please type 'Etherpad Lite rocks my socks' or supply the
'--root' argument if you still want to start it as root"
   read rocks
   if [ ! $rocks = "Etherpad Lite rocks my socks" ]
   then
     echo "Your input was incorrect"
exit 1 fi

fi 

Start etherpad-lite with the command: bin/run.sh
```

This didn't work out as well! -.-

Now I am not sure how to handle it, I really need to use etherpad urgently for a project, so I would be very thankful for any solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you made sure you have all dependencies. on the Github page it say following dependencies are required:
`apt-get install gzip git-core curl python libssl-dev pkg-config build-essential` For Ubuntu
`yum install gzip git-core curl python openssl-devel && yum groupinstall` For Fedora

Comment: Basically run these commands based on your OS and it will install whichever is needed.

Comment: yes,...build-essential is already the newest version.
curl is already the newest version.
git-core is already the newest version.
gzip is already the newest version.
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
pkg-config is already the newest version.
python is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: The messages related to jQuery are normal, i ran it myself and it is working for me. You can update your nodejs and npm and try again, and make sure that port number `9001` is free.

Comment: nodejs and npm are both on the newest version. I checked with `netstat -antp` for the used ports, `9001` was not included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a naming conflict with the node package (Amateur Packet Radio Node Program), and the nodejs binary has been renamed from node to nodejs. You'll need to symlink /usr/bin/node to /usr/bin/nodejs or you could uninstall the Amateur Packet Radio Node Program to avoid that conflict.

solution:
delete the node package:

```
apt-get remove node
```

then:

```
cd /usr/bin

ln -s nodejs node
```

then just run:
in the etherpad-lite directory

```
bin/run.sh
```

and it works ... =)

Answer (score 0):

cd to your etherpad folder, type

```
cd src && npm install
```

Then type

```
cd .. && bin/run.sh
```

If that fails type

```
rm -Rf src/node_modules
```

Then

```
bin/run.sh
```

Comment: it didn't work, when I typed in `npm install` I got the following message: `by nmp install I get the following ` ...
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies

npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-d"
npm ERR! cwd /home/xyz/nodejs/etherpad-lite/test1
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.10
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, open 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/xyz/nodejs/etherpad-lite/test1/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0`